# How can I plot unequal discrete colorbar using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster

I am a beginner in R language. I'm trying to plot a raster image with ggplot2, but I'm having trouble setting up the colorbar. Since my data has a large range and the density is concentrated in a small range, I want to bin the continuous data. But obviously, the result of my binning like this is that **these intervals are not equal**. The problem I'm having now is that I can't customize the colorbar to my needs.This is the colorbar form I want:
[the colorbar I WANT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CAo9.png)

I tried some commonly used functions and found that scale_fill_viridis_b() can meet my needs. This is my code:

```
my_breaks <- c(-300,-2,-0.8,-0.4,-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1 )
ggplot(df)+
  geom_raster(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=sum))+
  scale_fill_viridis_b(direction=-1,breaks=my_breaks)
```

[These code output colorbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2ZAZ.png).
**But the problem is that this function can't modify its color, I can't set the corresponding color ramp.**

Also, I CAN'T provide my data for some reason of confidentiality. I am really sorry about that. And I can't post photos due to insufficient contribution, please click the link to view the corresponding photos.

Comment: Hi Geoffrey. Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm afraid it's difficult to give you any specific help with the information you have provided. We don't have data that reproduces the issue you describe, nor the code you are using, nor what precisely is wrong with your current output, nor a clear idea of exactly what the desired output is. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include these things?

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you for your comment. This is indeed my question, I will edit my question for more readability. Thanks again!